# BuildApk in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, build

I build an apk then I install it on several phones and it works correctly, but when I install it on a Samsung Note 5 and click on a special part of app, it crashes.

I don't find any error in code, I log it but I don't find anything. If I build the apk using another PC everything is ok. If I run the app in the phone by connect it to pc there isn't any error.

Edit: I solved my problem by using ACRA lib that send report to your email so I found out where is problem. if you have the same issue, it can be useful: https://github.com/ACRA/acra

When I use BuildApk(debug build) in android studio, when I want to install every app in my phone I receive a warning block by play protect and developer is unknown.

Comment: is release build or debug buid?

Comment: fortunately, I can find reason of this problem! I use ACRA lib so I can receive error in my email. but I have had warning block when I use build apk yet!

Answer (score 1):

If you provide your logcat information, then you get the right answer.
As far as i know, there are some common mistake caused this kinds of crash,

1. SVG image related issue
2. Large image size related issue
3. Less heap size
4. OS version related issue
5. If you use fragment then context related issue (context getting null)
6. Build variants related issue
7. If you use Localization, then string file related issue. e.t.c

Better you provide your actual logcat data to find out the actual scenario.

Comment: thanks for your answer.I could solve my first problem but yet there is second problem about warning block by play protected when I install it on my phone

Comment: what is your phone model & os ?

Comment: in all device I have this problem that I can't use debug build

Answer (score 0):

which api does the samsung phone belong to?.if it is lower versions and your functionality is advanced you need to try if condition

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21){
     //your code
}else{
     lower versions
}
```